# Получить несколько переменных из функции через return

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Есть функция, например:

```
def func():
    r = requests.get('mysite.com')
    r1 = r.cookies('example1')
    r2 = r.cookies('example2')

    return r1, r2
```

Как мне получить значения `r1` и `r2` максимально удобно из конструкции типа:

```
z1 = func()
z2 = func()
```

но не вызывая функцию два раза и чтобы `z1` присвоился строго `r1`, а `z2`- строго `r2`?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is it pythonic for a function to return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61605/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Присвойте оба значения сразу:

```
z1, z2 = func()
```

Comment: то есть положение в кортеже r1 и r2 всегда будет неизменным? (сначала r1, потом r2)

Comment: @babyborn Да, именно в таком порядке.

Answer (score 7):

Строго говоря, функция в Python всегда возвращает ОДНО значение. Однако это значение - любого типа. Например -  кортеж, который вы можете распаковать указанными способами. Для удобства чтения кода пишут как у вас:

```
return r1, r2
```

однако точно так же все будет работать, если вы подчеркнете тот факт, что возвращается кортеж явно указав скобки:

```
return (r1, r2)
```

где-то в PEP-8 рекомендуется первый ("ваш") вариант, однако иногда это приводит даже к синтаксическим ошибкам!!
Не могу вспомнить где я это видел, но пример такой:

```
def foo():
    l = [1,2,3]
    a0, *a = l
    return a0, *a
```

выдает ошибку, а это :

```
def foo():
    l = [1,2,3]
    a0, *a = l
    return (a0, *a)
```

нет!

Answer (score 6):

Функция func() возвращает кортеж (r1, r2)
Если Вы выполните:

```
r1_2 = func()
```

В r1_2 будет кортеж (r1, r2), к которому можно обращаться по индексу:

```
z1 = r1_2[0] 
z2 = r1_2[1]
```

Можно сократить код, воспользовавшись особой магией питона:

```
z1, z2 = func()
```